# How to write WHERE clause with one of the conditions being the result of a calculated field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I have a calculated field in my query that looks like this:

```
(SELECT avg(RateAmount)/1.15
FROM ReservationStayDate f
where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT'
```

In the same query, I need to exclude all data where RatePlan begins with 'CO' AND the above result = 0

In other words, my WHERE clause need to look something like this:

```
AND NOT (d.rateplan like 'CO%' and (avg(RateAmount)/1.15)= 0)
```

I'm getting this error message: Invalid column name 'RateAmount'

What's wrong with the syntax here?

HERE IS THE FULL QUERY:

```
SELECT a.ReservationStayID,
   b.PropertyCode AS'Property',
   b.ReservationStatus AS 'Status',
   d.rsl_rateplan AS 'Rate Plan Code',
   b.MarketSegmentCode AS 'Market Segment',
   e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS 'Source of Business',
   a.ArrivalDate AS 'Date of Arrival',
   a.DepartureDate AS 'Date of Departure',
   c.AdultCount AS 'Adult',
   c.ChildCount AS 'Child',
   b.GuestCount AS 'Guest',
   d.rsl_nationality AS 'Nationality',
   c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
   c.CurrencyCode As 'Currency',
   e.Name AS 'Tour Operator',
   e.CountryCode AS 'Market Code',
   g.CountryGroup AS 'Market',


 (SELECT avg(RateAmount)/1.15
  FROM ReservationStayDate f
  where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT'

  FROM GuestNameInfo a
  JOIN GuestStaySummary b ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
  LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
  LEFT JOIN Market g ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode

  WHERE a.PrimaryGuest='+' and d.rsl_primaryguest='+'

  AND A.ARRIVALDATE <= '2013-09-30' AND A.DEPARTUREDATE > '2013-09-01'

  ORDER BY a.ReservationStayID
```

Comment: You can't refer to RateAmount as you probably don't have the table (ReservationStayDate) in your main query.  If you add it to your main query then it will produce multiple rows per ReservationStayID so that wouldn't help.  You probably need to perform the query in two passes, one to get the data and one to filter the results?

Comment: If I include a column from ReservationStayDate in my main Query, then it will work?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your full query I can't give an exact solution, but in SQL Server you can use [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which will works like a subselect, but it will allow you to reuse the column created, and also create multiple columns. e.g.

```
SELECT  a.SomeField,
        r.RateAmountExcVat
FROM    SomeTable AS a
        INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable AS d
            ON d.SomeField = a.SomeField
        --... Whatever else your query does...
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  RateAmountExcVat = AVG(RateAmount)/1.15
            FROM    ReservationStayDate AS f
            WHERE   f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
        ) AS r
WHERE   NOT (d.RatePlan LIKE 'CO%' AND r.RateAmountExcVat = 0);
```

However, you don't necessarily need to use a correlated subquery, a normal subuery would work exactly the same. So rather than doing the aggregation in your select clause, you can move the aggregation to a subquery, meaning you can reference the result of the aggregation in the outer query.

```
SELECT  a.SomeField,
        r.RateAmountExcVat
FROM    SomeTable AS a
        INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable AS d
            ON d.SomeField = a.SomeField

        --... Whatever else your query does...

        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  ReservationStayID,
                    RateAmountExcVat = AVG(RateAmount)/1.15
            FROM    ReservationStayDate AS f
            GROUP BY ReservationStayID
        ) AS r
            ON r.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
WHERE   NOT (d.RatePlan LIKE 'CO%' AND r.RateAmountExcVat = 0);
```

---

**EDIT**

Your full query would be something like this.

```
SELECT  a.ReservationStayID,
        b.PropertyCode AS [Property],
        b.ReservationStatus AS [Status],
        d.rsl_rateplan AS [Rate Plan Code],
        b.MarketSegmentCode AS [Market Segment],
        e.TravelAgencyTypeCode AS [Source of Business],
        a.ArrivalDate AS [Date of Arrival],
        a.DepartureDate AS [Date of Departure],
        c.AdultCount AS [Adult],
        c.ChildCount AS [Child],
        b.GuestCount AS [Guest],
        d.rsl_nationality AS [Nationality],
        c.PMSConfirmationNumber,
        c.CurrencyCode As [Currency],
        e.Name AS [Tour Operator],
        e.CountryCode AS [Market Code],
        g.CountryGroup AS [Market],
        f.RateAmountExclVAT AS [Rate Amount Excl.VAT]
FROM    GuestNameInfo a
        JOIN GuestStaySummary b 
            ON a.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
        LEFT JOIN ReservationStay c 
            ON c.ReservationStayID = b.ReservationStayID
        LEFT JOIN P5RESERVATIONLIST d 
            ON d.rsl_code = b.ReservationStayID
        LEFT JOIN TravelAgency e 
            ON e.TravelAgencyID = c.TAProfileID
        LEFT JOIN Market g 
            ON e.CountryCode = g.CountryCode
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  ReservationStayID, 
                    RateAmountExclVAT = AVG(RateAmount) / 1.15
            FROM    ReservationStayDate f
            GROUP BY f.ReservationStayID
        ) AS f
            ON f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
WHERE   a.PrimaryGuest='+' 
AND     d.rsl_primaryguest='+'
AND     A.ARRIVALDATE <= '2013-09-30' 
AND     A.DEPARTUREDATE > '2013-09-01'
AND     NOT (d.RatePlan like 'CO%' AND f.RateAmountExclVAT = 0)
ORDER BY a.ReservationStayID
```

A couple of things worth noting is that I have removed you `AS 'alias'` syntax since using literals as column aliases is deprecated. [Further reading in [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) . I'd also recommend [using meaning table aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) rather than just a, b, c etc.

Comment: Thanks GarethD...I've edited the post with my full query. Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks a lot, GarethD! Highly appreciated! Shouldn't the r.RateAmountExclVAT be f.RateAmountExclVAT?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * from ReservationStayDate M
join
(SELECT f.ReservationStayID,avg(RateAmount)/1.15 R
FROM ReservationStayDate f
where f.ReservationStayID = a.ReservationStayID
and  d.rateplan not like 'CO%'
 group by    f.ReservationStayID
) AS E
on  E.ReservationStayID = M.ReservationStayID 
where E.r = 0
```

or try this

```
(SELECT E.R
FROM ReservationStayDate f
join
    (SELECT f.ReservationStayID,avg(RateAmount)/1.15 R
    FROM ReservationStayDate f1
    whered.rateplan not like 'CO%'
     group by    f.ReservationStayID
    ) AS E
    on  E.ReservationStayID = F.ReservationStayID 
where E.r = 0

) AS 'Rate Amount Excl.VAT'
```

Comment: I can't because I am pulling data from other tables in my query (I showed just a part of the query in my question) and I need only the average Rate Amount from the table ReservationStayDate.

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY f.ReservationStayID` in your subquery. This answer would be substantially improved with even a single sentence explaining what changes you have made and why, instead of just "Try this".

Comment: I get this error message: "The multi-part identifier "f.ReservationStayID" could not be bound."

Answer (score 0):

Take your existing query and remove this bit of the WHERE clause:

```
and (avg(RateAmount)/1.15)= 0
```

then rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (

<your original query>

) a WHERE a.[Rate Amount Excl.VAT] != 0;
```

That isn't the prettiest way to do it, but without the full query...